# Merge three numpy arrays, keep largest value

Tags: python, numpy

I want to merge three numpy arrays, for example:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
b = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
c = np.array([[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,1,0]])

a = array([[0, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [1, 0, 0]])

b = array([[1, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 1]])

c = array([[0, 1, 0],
           [0, 2, 0],
           [0, 1, 0]])
```

Desired result would be to overlay them but keep the largest value where multiple elements are not 0, like in the middle.

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

I solved this by iterating over all elements with multiple if-conditions. Is there a more compact and more beautiful way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NumPy's [`np.ufunc.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) allows to apply a function cumulatively along a given axis. We can just concatenate the arrays and reduce with [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to keep the accumulated elementwise maximum:

```
np.maximum.reduce([a,b,c])

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try of stacking arrays together in extra dimension with Numpy [np.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) method

and  extract the maximum value specific to added dimension

```
# Stacking arrays together
d = np.dstack([a,b,c])
d.max(axis=2)
```

Out:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```